# How to create html table in for loop of php script?

Tags: php, html

I would like to create table for the below for loop. It prints the square of numbers from 1 to 10. I want to declare a html table and want to show the output like this

"1 square is" one cell, "1" in second cell
"2 square is" in one cell, "4" in second cell

```
<?php
for ($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
echo $i . ' square is ' .  $i*$i . "<br>";
?>
```

Thanks alot.

Comment: you can make use of `sprintf` function as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
echo '<table>';
for ($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
echo '<tr><td>' . $i . ' square is </td><td>' .  $i*$i . "</td></tr>";
echo '</table>';
?>
```